# Table type variable use as loop index in oracle

Tags: oracle, loops, types

I created table type

```
 create or replace TYPE NUMBER_ARRAY 
    AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

I want to select `PERIODS` value one by one in loop

```
 DECLARE PERIODS NUMBER_ARRAY;
 BEGIN
   FOR P IN(SELECT * FROM TABLE (PERIODS))
   LOOP
     SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p);
   END LOOP;
 END;
```

I get this error

> wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PUT_LINE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P` is of `record` data type. `put_line()` procedure expects character string or any other value that can be implicitly or explicitly converted to one. When you query a simple nested table collection, only one column will be returned, named `COLUMN_VALUE`. So, after putting it all together your code should look something like this:

```
 DECLARE PERIODS NUMBER_ARRAY;
 BEGIN
   FOR P IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (PERIODS))
   LOOP
     /*
      Since elements of the collection are of NUMBER data type
      it's better to convert them to a character explicitly
      rather than allow Oracle to do it implicitly, thus the use
      of TO_CHAR() function.
     */
     SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(to_char(p.column_value));
   END LOOP;
 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

### try this:

```
 DECLARE PERIODS NUMBER_ARRAY;
 BEGIN
 --PERIODS := NUMBER_ARRAY (1, 2, 3); example for you
 FOR P IN 
 (
 SELECT * FROM TABLE (PERIODS)
 )
 LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(P.column_value );
 END LOOP;
 END;
```